# Weird comparison performance on Javascript object key lookup

Tags: javascript, node.js, dictionary, time, comparison

## Presentation :

I am working on a piece of code that can compare two javascript Object by looping into the first one (called A) to perform a key lookup in the second one called B (I put value as key and occurence as value).

But when I am measuring the performance of the subkey key lookup of Object A (10 times per amount of data, with data as changing parameters for each 10 times the program runs (100 per row, 200...) I get high timing for the smallest amount of data (so potentially less key in the dict B)

## Objects layout :

Object A looks like below:

```
{
 SQL_TABLE_1:
 {
     column_1:
      [ 
        '2jmj7l5rSfeb/vlWAYkK/YBwIDk=',
        '3MaRDFGBKvsLLhrLUdplz3wUiOI=',
        'PEvUFHDR4HbOYXcj7danOvyRJqs='
        'XHvERAKZ4AqU+iWlx2scZXdem80=',
        'nSG0lvwlkIe5YxZGTo5binr3pAw=',
        'Swuc/7YCU9Ptfrff+KHaJJ1+b7U=',
        'N28qqdfezfZbPmK7CaGmj7m7IOQ=',
        'ffc7skeffegT1ZytAqjco3EpwUE=',
        '2XldayBefzBxsUuu6tMFYHVZEEY=',
        '5rC2y6IzadQ1aEy7CvNyr30JJ2k='
      ]
 },
 SQL_TABLE_2:
   {
      column_1:[......]
   }
}
```

Object B field have various size but this size never change in our tests
And Object B looks like:

```
[
field_1:
 { 
  '2jmj7l5rSfeb/vlWAYkK/YBwIDk=': 1,
  '3MaRDFGBKvsLLhrLUdplz3wUiOI=': 1,
  'PEvUFHDR4HbOYXcj7danOvyRJqs=': 1,
  'XHvERAKZ4AqU+iWlx2scZXdem80=': 4,
  'nSG0lvwlkIe5YxZGTo5binr3pAw=': 1,
  'Swuc/7YCU9Ptfrff+KHaJJ1+b7U=': 1,
  'N28qqdfezfZbPmK7CaGmj7m7IOQ=': 27,
  'ffc7skeffegT1ZytAqjco3EpwUE=': 1,
  '2XldayBefzBxsUuu6tMFYHVZEEY=': 18,
  '5rC2y6IzadQ1aEy7CvNyr30JJ2k=': 1 },
field_2:{......}
]
```

Timing measurement in the code is structured like this:

```
    sql_field_1:
    {
       mongo_field_1: 0.003269665241241455, mongo_field_2: 0.0015446391105651855, mongo_field_3: 0.0009834918975830079, mongo_field_4: 0.0004488091468811035,
    },
    sql_field_2:
    {
        ....
    }
```

## Goal

The goal is to perform for each sub-subkey of Object A a key lookup on the Object B subkeys.

## Code

Here's the code that cause this behavior:
Object A is called sql_dict_array
Object B is called hash_mongo_dict

```
    for(var field_name in hash_mongo_dict)
        {       
            performance_by_mongo_field[field_name] = {};
            result_by_mongo_field[field_name] = {};
            // LOOP ON OBJECT A KEYS
            for(var table_name in sql_dict_array)
            {
                // Start of time measurement
                var start_time = performance.now();


                // there is only one column in our test data
                for(var column_name in sql_dict_array[table_name])
                {   
                    found_count = 0;

                    for(var value of sql_dict_array[table_name][column_name])
                    {   
                        // **SUBKEY LOOPKUP HERE WITH VALUE**
                        var results = hash_mongo_dict[field_name][value];
                        // IF NOT UNDEFINED THEN IT HAS BEEN FOUND
                        // THIS CHECK IS NOT THE BOTTLENECK
                        if(results != undefined)
                        { 
                            found_count+=results;
                        }
                    }
                    if(found_count > limit_parameter)
                    {
                        console.log("error: too many match between hashes")
                        process.exit(0)
                    }
                    // PERFORMANCE CALCULATION
                    performance_by_mongo_field[field_name][table_name] = (performance.now() - start_time)/1000;
                    result_by_mongo_field[field_name][table_name+'.'+column_name] = (found_count/verif_hash_count*100);

                }
            }
         return some results...
        }
```

## Testing:

With this code, I expect to have almost **constant time** whatever the size of the Object B (amount of subkey) but in my code I have higher time when I have only 10 subkeys in the nested object A, and it become stable when reaching 100 keys or more (tested with 6000 keys)

Here's 10 runs for the key lookup code of one key of Object A containing **10 subkeys** with 300.000+ data from Object B:

0.2824700818061829 0.2532380700111389 0.2455208191871643 0.2610406551361084 0.2840422649383545 0.2344329071044922 0.2375670108795166 0.23545906591415405 0.23111085414886476 0.2363566837310791

Here's the same comparison but with **4000+ subkeys**:

0.0027927708625793456 0.0018292622566223144 0.015235211849212647 0.0036304402351379395 0.002919149875640869 0.004972007751464844 0.014655702114105225 0.003572652339935303 0.0032280778884887697 0.003232938766479492

I will appreciate every advice you can provide me,

Comment: Your object A definition is not valid, is it an object of arrays?

Comment: Yes thanks for pointing that out I've update the question, I'll appreciate any advice you can provide to me

Comment: Getting there, now please try putting performance measurements exactly around the (supposedly) critical instructions. I assume you think it's the subkey lookup right? 
ps: I think it can come down to the result of the undefined check being too random, causing branch prediction to fail.

Comment: Having removed the 'undefined check' part changed nothing to the performance results unfortunatly, also concerning the measure wrapping this is the lowest I can go to get timing like this:
```JSON

   sql_field_1:
   { mongo_field_1: 0.003269665241241455,
     mongo_field_2: 0.0015446391105651855,
     mongo_field_3: 0.0009834918975830079,
     mongo_field_4: 0.0004488091468811035,
},
sql_field_2:{....}
```

Comment: I also wrote these in the main post

Comment: You got way too many loops in your code for the Object A and Object B you've shown. Are they actually even more deeply nested?

Comment: Most of your variables (especially the looping variables) seem to be global, as you didn't declare them anywhere. Is this your actual code? Especially for questions about performance, please provide a complete [reprex].

Comment: Also I tried to shorten the code but this is the shortest I can get without being too narrow in the logic of the program

Comment: (repost of first answer to Bergi)

Thank you for taking your time,& I've clarified a bit the exemple in the post, I've update the Object A(sql_dict_array) since I forget one level of nesting thanks for pointing that out, and the first loop for the other object B seems fine to me, it's only looping through the field_1 and field_2 key to get these arrays of value

Comment: I've also updated the code to declare loop variable but nothing changed, feel free to give me any advice or recommandation

Comment: I've shorten the problem on this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57256876/key-lookup-and-intersection-slower-with-less-keys-and-weird-performance